# Plotting values of a column based on condition value of another column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

My df looks like this,

```
id |      Start_time     | Grades 
swe  2019-04-01 15:30:00    0.54
few  2019-04-01 15:30:00    0.43
yre  2019-04-01 15:00:00    0.98
```

I want to call or plot all grades where the start_time is any specific time or ***2019-04-01 15:30:00*** for example and plot or call all values under grades for that start time, how can I do this?

I tried something like `df[df['Start_time'] == '2019-04-04 06:00:00']['Grades']`

But doesnt seem to work

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to filter the data for specific date and plot the Grades column.

```
d = df.loc[df["Start_time"] == "2019-04-01 15:30:00"]
d['Grades'].plot.bar() # or just plot() if a line graph
```

Note that this will plot the `Grades` values as they are - since you didn't mention about the X axis.

Edit:

One liner:

```
df.loc[df["Start_time"] == "2019-04-01 15:30:00"]['Grades'].plot.bar()
```